# Hibernate Criteria to Join two tables to fetch data from both tables

Tags: hibernate

I have following scenario in which I want to fetch different columns from two table into one entity:

Entity 1: Table -> `TBL_DISCUSSION`

```
public class Discussion{
private int discussionId;// primary key
private int discussionText;
private String createByUserId;// Foreign Key (TBL_USER.userId)
private String createByUserFullName;// This is just a property, and does not have   stored into table
private Timestamp createTimestamp;
}
```

Entity 2: 
Table -> `TBL_USER`

```
public class User{
    private int userId;// primary key
    private int userFullName;
}
```

Now, what I need to do is that I have to fetch all the discussions from TBL_DISCUSSION and also fetch `UserFullName` for every discussion creater but we only store `userId` (`createByUserId`) into `TBL_DISCUSSION` table and user's full name lies in `TBL_USER` table.

How, do I write a criteria to do achieve this?

Comment: Format your code, and read about associations. Discussion shouldn't have a userId and a user full name, but a ManyToOne association with User.

Comment: As @JBNizet wrote you can't use Criteria with join because entity need to be related with correct annotation (as `ManyToOne`, for eg)